# How many domains we can include while creating a filter in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Someone tell me the number of domains to be included while creating filter in gmail inbox
for example
    from:(-*@gt.com -*@syscloud.com) label:inbox -in:chats

Comment: Is their any character limit in the creation of filter ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/